# Django responding to different request from different browser with one python session

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, bitnami

I'm actually a php(CodeIgniter) web developer though I love python I just installed [Bitnami's Django Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/django) which has Apache, MySQL, PostgreSQL and Python 2.7.9 with Django installed. During installation itself it generated a simple Django project.

Though it looked familiar to me I started adding some lines of codes to it but when I save it and refresh the page or even restart the browser I found that python instance is still running the old script. The script updates only when I restart start the Apache Server(I believe that's where the Python instance got terminated).

So, to clarify this problem with Python I created a simple view and URLed it to `r'^test/'`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

i = 0

def test_view(request):
    global i
    i += 1
    return HttpResponse(str(i))
```

Then I found that even switching between different browser the `i` value keep on increasing i.e increasing value continues with the other browse.

So, can anyone tell me is this a default behavior of Django or is there something wrong with my Apache installation.

Comment: This is why a) you don't use global variables in a web app and b) you use the dev server, rather than Apache, for development.

Comment: If this thing works in this way how MySQL session lock can be possible bcos it seems like the python session never ended even though there is nothing to process.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean. What does the MySQL session lock have to do with anything? Why would you want to lock tables at all? What Python session are you talking about?

Comment: I think I might be confused about MySQL session lock. But this seems completely different from what I known from PHP bcos in PHP $_SESSION is a global variable but it differs for each and every user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior, it *may* reset if you were running with gunicorn and killing workers after X requests or so, I don't remember. It's like this because the app continues to run after a request has been served.

Its been a while I've worked with PHP but I believe, a request comes in, php starts running a script which returns output and then that script terminates. Special global variables like `$_SESSION` aside, nothing can really cross requests.

Your Django app starts up and continues to run unless something tells it to reload (when running with `./manage.py runserver` it will reload whenever it detects changes to the code, this is what you want during development).

If you are interested in per visitor data see [session data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions). It would look something like:

```
request.session['i'] = request.session.get('i', 0) + 1
```

You can store data in there for the visitor and it will stick around until they lose their session.

Comment: So unlike PHP which create a separate instance for every request, Django works with only one instance for all the requests and is this what makes Django not asynchronous?